# How to implement a brute force solution to "Finding first unique character in a string"

Tags: python, algorithm

As described here:
https://leetcode.com/problems/first-unique-character-in-a-string/description/

I attempted one here but couldn't quite finish:
https://paste.pound-python.org/show/JuPLgdgqceMQYh5kk0Sf/

```
#Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.
#xamples:
#s = "leetcode"
#return 0.

#s = "loveleetcode",
#return 2.
#Note: You may assume the string contain only lowercase letters.

class Solution(object):
    def firstUniqChar(self, s):
        """
        :type s: str
        :rtype: int
        """
        for i in range(len(s)):
            for j in range(i+1,len(s)):
                if s[i] == s[j]:
                    break          
               #But now what. let's say i have complete loop of j where there's no match with i, how do I return i?
```

I'm ONLY interested in the brute force N^2 solution, nothing fancier. The idea in the above solution is to start a double loop, where inner loop searches for a match with the outer loop's char, and if there's match, break the inner loop and continue onto the next char on the outer loop.

But the question is, how do I handle when there's NO match, which is when I need to return the outer loop's index as the first unique one.

Can't quite figure out a graceful way to do it, and can handle edge case like a single char string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each char, and check if it appears in any of the following chars. We need to keep track of the characters we've already seen, to avoid falling into edge cases. Try this, it's an `O(n^2)` solution:

```
def firstUniqChar(s):
    # store already seen chars
    seen = []
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        # return if char not previously seen and not in rest
        if c not in seen and c not in s[i+1:]:
            return i
        # mark char as seen
        seen.append(c)
    # no unique chars were found
    return -1
```

For completeness' sake, here's an `O(n)` solution:

```
def firstUniqChar(s):
    # build frequency table
    freq = {}
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if c not in freq:
            # store [frequency, index]
            freq[c] = [1, i]
        else:
            # update frequency
            freq[c][0] += 1
    # find leftmost char with frequency == 1
    # it's more efficient to traverse the freq table
    # instead of the (potentially big) input string
    leftidx = float('+inf')
    for f, i in freq.values():
        if f == 1 and i < leftidx:
            leftidx = i
    # handle edge case: no unique chars were found
    return leftidx if leftidx != float('+inf') else -1
```

For example:

```
firstUniqChar('cc')
=> -1
firstUniqChar('ccdd')
=> -1
firstUniqChar('leetcode')
=> 0
firstUniqChar('loveleetcode')
=> 2
```

Comment: What if input is 'cc'

Comment: @user1008636 Doesn't that go to `return None`?

Comment: Nope, it'll go to the Else.

Comment: There were a couple of edge cases I wasn't considering. Please check my updated, _tested_ answer.

Comment: I just added an `O(n)` solution, for the heck of it :)

Comment: Thank you, the O(n) solution was brilliant.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else` to the `for` loop where you return.

```
for j ...:
   ...
else:
  return i
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd first like to note that your current algorithm for finding unique characters doesn't work correctly. That's because you can't assume the character at index `i` is unique just because none of the indexes `j` found the same character later in the string. The character at index `i` could be a repeat of an earlier character (which you'd have skipped when the previous `j` was equal to the current `i`).

You could fix the algorithm by letting `j` iterate over the whole range of indexes, and adding an extra check to ignore the matches when the indexes are the same to your `if`:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        if i != j and s[i] == s[j]:
            break
```

As [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) suggests in his answer, you can then add an `else` block to the inner `for` loop to make the code return when no match was found:

```
    else:   # this line should be indented to match the "for j" loop
        return i
```

There are also a few ways you can solve this problem more simply if you use the builtin functions and types available in Python.

For instance, you can implement an `O(n^2)` solution equivalent to the one above using only one explicit loop, and using `str.count` to replace the inner one:

```
def firstUniqChar(s):
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if s.count(c) == 1:
            return i
    return None
```

I'm also using `enumerate` to get the character values and indexes together in one step, rather than iterating over a `range` and indexing later.

There's also a very easy way to make an `O(n)` solution using `collections.Counter`, which can do all the counting in one pass before you start checking the characters in order to try to find the first one that is unique:

```
from collections import Counter

def firstUniqChar(s):
    count = Counter(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        if count[c] == 1:
            return i
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your approach will work on an even palindrome, e.g. `"redder"` (note the second `d`).  Try this instead:

```
s1 = "leetcode"
s2 = "loveleetcode"
s3 = "redder"


def unique_index(s):
    ahead, behind = list(s), set()
    for idx, char in enumerate(s):
        ahead = ahead[1:]
        if (char not in ahead) and (char not in behind):
            return idx
        behind.add(s[idx])
    return -1


assert unique_index(s1) == 0
assert unique_index(s2) == 2
assert unique_index(s3) == -1
```

For each character, we look ahead and behind.  Only characters disjoint from both groups will return an index.  As iteration progresses, the list of what is observed `ahead` shortens, while what is seen `behind` extends.  The default is `-1` as stated in the actual leetcode challenge.

A second list is not required.  @Óscar López's answer is the simplified answer.